There is a line on the transformer in my figure. How do I get rid of it? The code and its output is given

\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
  \ctikzset{capacitors/height=.4}
  \ctikzset{resistors/width=.6}
 
  \draw (0,0) to [C, l=$C_1$] (1,1)
  to [R, l=$R_1$] (2,2) -- (3,3) -- (4,2)
  to [R, l=$R_3$] (5,1) -- (6,0)
  -- (5,-1) to [C, l=$C_4$] (4,-2) --
  (3,-3) -- (3,-1.2) to [L, l=$$] (3,0) -- (3,0.5) to [C, l=$C_3$]
  (1.5,0.5) node[ground]{};
  
  \draw (3,0) -- (3,3);
  
  \draw (3,-3) -- (2,-2) to [C, l=$C_2$] (1,-1) -- (0,0);
  
  \draw (0,0) -- (-1,0) -- (-1,-4) -- (2,-4);
 
  \draw (1.1,-4.1) to node[transformer core, rotate=90, transform
      shape]{} (5,-6);
 
  \draw (5,-6) -- (7,-6) -- (7,0) -- (6,0);
  \draw (4,-2) -- (5,-3) to [R, l=$R_4$] (6.3,-1.6) -- (5.3,-0.7) ;
 
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Just as supplement to nice @Rmano answer.
It seems that code for your circuit is not complete. As it is drawn, it can't work ... so I a wee bit change connection of transformer to the bridge (should it be Wien's bridge?), but you can easily revert to your original connection.
By use of the TikZ library ext.paths.ortho the MWE can be:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{capacitors/width=0.1, capacitors/height=0.5,
          resistors/width=.5}
% bridge
\draw   (-2.4, 0.0) to [C=$C_1$]    (-1.2, 1.2)
                    to [R=$R_1$]    ( 0.0, 2.4)
                    to [R=$R_3$]    ( 2.4, 0.0)  -- ++ (-0.6,-0.6) coordinate (a)
                    to [C=$C_4$] ++ (-1.2,-1.2)  coordinate (b)  -- ( 0.0,-2.4)
                    to [C=$C_2$]    (-2.4, 0.0)
        (a) -- ++ (0.9,-0.9)to [R=$R_4$] ++(-1.2,-1.2) -- (b)
%
        ( 0.0,-2.4) to [L]          ( 0.0, 0.6) -- (0,2.4)
        ( 0.0, 0.6) to [C=$C_3$] ++ (-1.0, 0.0)  node[ground]{};
% transformer
\node (T) [transformer core, rotate=90, transform shape] at (0,-4.8) {};
% conections between bridge and transformer
\draw   (-2.4,0)    r-lr    (T.B1)
        ( 2.4,0)    r-rl    (T.B2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



BTW, you can transform your code to a real minimum one:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (1.1,-4.1) to node[transformer core, rotate=90, transform
      shape]{} (5,-6);
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

which shows the problem:

Now, examine the \draw command. What it says is:
\draw starting from  (1.1,-4.1) to ...and then TikZ search the second coordinate, which is (5,-6); so it draws a line (an unadorned to is the same as --). Then there is a node specification, without any pos argument, which means you want the node positioned in the middle of the line, after (as it happens for every node), the path is stroke.
So the solution(*) is to just position the node in the middle (remove the to); but probably what you really want is to position it relative to the connecting wires. The clean solution, instead of guessing coordinates, is to use anchors and a bit of perpendicular drawing (I added the color to show the process of building the diagram):
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (-1,0) -- (-1,-4) -- (2,-4);
    \draw (2,-4) node[transformer core, rotate=90, transform shape, anchor=B1](T){};
    \draw[blue]  (T.A2) -| (7,-6) -- (7,0) -- (6,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



(*) but please stop using absolute coordinates and learn relative and orthogonal ones; you'll have much cleaner, symmetric, and reusable circuits later...

I'm sorry i did not post the complete code, my bad! This is my first question ever on TeX. Thanks for helping me out.

@quantumjester6 you're welcome!

@Rmano, I have installed recent circuitikz   package (version 1.7.0 (2024/08/03)). With it I try to test your second example, but node transformer core was not rotated properly (inductors are rotated, but primary coils is put vertically above secondary, core is not rotated). I still use OS w10, updated yesterday. Do you have idea hat is going wrong?

@Zarko you're right and I am wrong, the transform shape is needed here.
